# Add effective error handling to Python Notebook in Azure Synapse Analytics

Tags: python, azure

I have some Python code that runs as part of an Azure Synapse Analytics Apache Spark Notebook (or Synapse Notebook) and would like to add effective error handling.  The code simply executes a given SQL script against the database.  The code runs but I sometimes see errors like `attempt to use closed connection`.  I would like to do the following:

- Improve code that I wrote through peer review
- <s>Can I improve the error handling?  eg pseudo-code `if connection still open close connection`</s>
- <s>The code using SQL auth works.  I would like to authenticate as the Managed Identity, I've tried using the object id of the MI in the connection string with `Authentication=ActiveDirectoryMsi` but it didn't work</s>

### Cell1 - parameters

```
pAccountName = 'someStorageAccount'
pContainerName = 'someContainer'
pRelativePath = '/raw/sql/some_sql_files/'
pFileName = 'someSQLscript.sql'
```

## Cell 2 - main

```
import pyodbc
from pyspark import SparkFiles

try:
    # Add the file to the cluster so we can view it
    sqlFilepath = f"""abfss://{pContainerName}""" + "@" + f"""{pAccountName}.dfs.core.windows.net{pRelativePath}{pFileName}"""
    sc.addFile(sqlFilepath, False)


    # Open the file for reading
    with open(SparkFiles.getRootDirectory() + f'/{pFileName}', 'r') as f:
        lines = f.read()    ## read all text from a file into a string


    # Open the database connection
    conn = pyodbc.connect( 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                        'SERVER=someServer.sql.azuresynapse.net;'
                        'DATABASE=someDatabase;UID=batchOnlyUser;'
                        'PWD=youWish;', autocommit = True )


    # Split the script into batches separated by "GO"
    for batch in lines.split("GO"):
        conn.execute(batch)  # execute the SQL statement

except:
    raise

finally:
    # Tidy up
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what someSQLscript contains?

Comment: It could be any sql script really, so anything from just `select @@version` to big create table, insert statements etc

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. We can review the code and make suggestions on how to improve it. We can't help you write new code or debug the code. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). At least 2 things are making the question off-topic, the first is that your valid concerns about security are making you use generic names. The second is that `Authentication=ActiveDirectoryMsi` doesn't work. We can only review working code.

Comment: @pacmaninbw Per e.g. https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/696/25834 I don't see the generic names as a problem, and it's common practice to omit or change credentials; that on its own is not a reason for closure.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, asks for code to be written, which is off-topic for Code Review. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Comment: So if I change it to “Review error handling...” instead of “Add effective ...” would that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring your closed-connection and managed-identity questions, since (a) I don't know how to answer them and (b) on their own they're off topic, there is still review to be done:

- A Pythonic way to tell the standard library to format your URI instead of you doing it yourself is to call into `urlunparse`
- Consider using `pathlib`
- `connect` accepts kwargs as an alternative to the conn string, and the former will lay out your connection parameters more nicely
- `except / raise` is redundant and should be deleted
- Your `try` starts too early and should only start *after* the connection has been established
- You're not reading a lines list; you're reading content, which would be a better variable name

### Suggested

```
from pathlib import Path
from urllib.parse import urlunparse, ParseResult
import pyodbc
from pyspark import SparkFiles


pAccountName = 'someStorageAccount'
pContainerName = 'someContainer'
pRelativePath = '/raw/sql/some_sql_files/'
pFileName = 'someSQLscript.sql'

# Add the file to the cluster so we can view it
sql_filename = urlunparse(
    ParseResult(
        scheme='abfss',
        netloc=f'{pContainerName}@{pAccountName}.dfs.core.windows.net',
        path=f'{pRelativePath}{pFileName}',
        params=None, query=None, fragment=None,
    )
)

sc.addFile(sql_filename, False)

# Open the file for reading
sql_file_path = Path(SparkFiles.getRootDirectory()) / pFileName
with sql_file_path.open() as f:
    content = f.read()

# Open the database connection
conn = pyodbc.connect(
    DRIVER='{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}',
    SERVER='someServer.sql.azuresynapse.net',
    DATABASE='someDatabase',
    UID='batchOnlyUser',
    PWD='youWish',
    autocommit=True,
)

try:
    # Split the script into batches separated by "GO"
    for batch in content.split("GO"):
        conn.execute(batch)  # execute the SQL statement
finally:
    conn.close()
```

Comment: ok useful, thank you.  I'm going to leave it open for a few days but have upvoted and will consider marking as answer later.